# when is an sms/mms message considered read by the system?

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I have a contentObserver that watches the unread count of text messages and clears a notification if the unread count = 0.

Question is when does the system decide a message is unread because the notification only gets cleared when someone reply's to the message which in my opinion seems a little weird since it was obviously read before you reply to it